# MATLAB Image Processing: Getting HSV components from a colored image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, hsv

I am trying to get the hue, saturation and value images from an image (originally colored). I converted the image using the `rgb2hsv()` function but I am confused on how to get the component images.

Answer (score 0):

As [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html)  mentions, the output of rgb2hsv is returned as an m-by-n-by-3 image array whose three planes contain the hue, saturation, and value components of the image.Therefore you can simply get these components as:

```
hsv_image = rgb2hsv(rgb_image);
hue_component= hsv_image(:,:,1);
saturation_component= hsv_image(:,:,2);
value _component= hsv_image(:,:,3);
```